# Adding parameters to a GUI constructor stops GUI pop up

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, constructor

I've started learning Java with Eclipse, and I altered the main function to pass two strings to the similarly altered GUI constructor (there was nothing passed before).

The GUI doesn't pop up on the screen now, but can be accessed from the task bar at the bottom of the screen. I was just wondering why this happened? I've pasted the shortened code below.

I've tried it multiple times, and tried to find the problem with keywords on the web.

```
public class MainButton 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String A = "title"; String B = "Button";
        Agui a = new Agui(A,B);

               //BEFORE Agui a = new Agui();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Agui extends JFrame 
{
    //BEFORE public Agui()
    public Agui(String A, String B) 
    {
        setTitle(A);
        setSize(400, 400);

        // Create JButton and JPanel
        JButton button = new JButton(B);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        // Add button to JPanel
        panel.add(button);
        // And JPanel needs to be added to the JFrame itself!
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }
}
```

It'd be great to get the pop up without going to the task bar at the bottom of the screen, and to understand the logic of why this problem occurs.

Comment: JFrame#setAlwaysOnTop()

Comment: Swing code must be executed on the AWT event dispatch thread.  Failure to do so leads to unpredictable behavior.  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details.  Quick fix is changing your `main` method’s second line to:  `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Agui(A, B));`